# Create an element spanning two Navbars

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

I have two Navbars which I looks like this:
[image]
I would want to add a banner that will help to understand that this site is a test site. It s[[image: ! enter image description here]

I would like to add a field that spans two Navbars and has text written on it. The following is the code that I have used for the two Navbars:

```
// First Navbar
<Navbar className="navbar-top" fixed="top">
    <Container>
        <Flex justify="flex-end" padding="0 20px 0 0">
        <NavDropdown onSelect={handleLanguageChange} alignRight title={language} id="basic-nav-dropdown">
            <NavDropdown.Item eventKey="EN">EN</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item eventKey="JP">JP</NavDropdown.Item>
        </NavDropdown>
        <NavDropdown onSelect={handleCurrencyChange} alignRight  title={currency} id="basic-nav-dropdown">
            <NavDropdown.Item eventKey="$ USD">$ USD</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item eventKey="¥ JPY">¥ JPY</NavDropdown.Item>
         </NavDropdown>
      </Flex>
   </Container>
</Navbar>

// Second Navbar
<Navbar variant="light" fixed="top" expand="lg" className="pt-4 pb-4 navbar-bottom">
    <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand href="/" className="d-none d-lg-block"><Image src={logo} width="200"></Image></Navbar.Brand>          

        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
        <Nav className="mr-auto">
            <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/" className="nav-2 ml-xl-4">{t('home')}</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link className="nav-2 ml-xl-4">{t('shop')}</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link className="nav-2 ml-xl-4">{t('sale')}</Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Container>
</Navbar>
```

I have no idea how to span the two Navbars, and add the text slantly.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a sideways banner over them like this..

The CSS...

```
.Sideways {

 position:absolute; top:200px; left:50px; padding:5px; border:1px solid black;

 width: 300px;  /* make it wider if required here */

 font-size: 35px;

 text-align: center;

 transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
}
```

The HTML

```
<div class="Sideways">Test Site</div>
```

Or is it a polygon you're looking for? :)

Comment: Hi, where to add this DIv?
in which Navbar?

For what I am using, it is not coming over the Navbars

Comment: The DIV should be placed after your navbars, and then adjust the left and top to wherever you want it to appear.

Comment: How do I add a polygon for this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the running example, you can place the div inside the body anywhere in your html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
    #triangle-topleft {
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-top: 100px solid red;
      border-right: 100px solid transparent;
      position: absolute;
    }
    #test-site-logo {
        position: absolute;
        top: 33px;
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
        left: 14px;        
    }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div id="triangle-topleft"></div>
        <div id="test-site-logo">Test site</div>
    </body>
</html>
```